# How design a MapReduce pseudo-code to count the number of documents that words appear?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I need to know the solution for this question but I need some help as I can't figure it out. Thanks for your time.

How can the mapper function be modified so that the program computes the document frequency for each distinct word (i.e., the number of documents containing that word)?

```
 class MAPPER
 method MAP(docid i, doc d)
 for all term t ∈ doc d do 
 EMIT(term t, count 1)

 class REDUCER
 method REDUCE(term t, counts [c1, c2, . . .])
 sum ← 0
 for all count c ∈ counts [c1,c2,...] do
 sum ← sum + c 
 EMIT(term t, count sum)
```

My solution, but I don't know if it is correct.

```
 class MAPPER
 method MAP(docid i, doc d)
   for all term t ∈ doc d do
     for all document d ∈ doc d do
      EMIT(term t, count + 1)
```

Comment: why have u removed my tags?

Answer (score 1):

I hope the following steps might help you. I just brief you the idea and you may convert it as an algorithm.

- At first, you have to find the file name of the input split being
  processed by mapper in your mapper class's `setup()` method. Refer
  below snippet,

  ```
  String fileName = ((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath().toString();
  ```
- From your Mapper class's `map()` method, emit every word as key and
  value as the string concated with file name found in setup() and int
  value 1.
- From your Reducer class's `reduce()` method, for every distinct word
  you will get list of strings where every string will contain
  corresponding file name and count 1.
- Iterate over the List of values of every key, and split every value ,
  then store the file name in a non-duplicate local collection like HashSet
  and do sum of the count 1.
- After iteration over List of values, you will get the sum of all
  count 1 and also a HashSet with distinct file names for the current
  key. Here size of the HashSet will be the document frequency of the
  key.
- Emit the key, word count and document frequency from the reducer and then reset the sum variable and the HashSet.